# Sniff UDP packets using VBscript

Tags: vbscript, udp

I need to monitor UDP packets received by a unit using VBscript . I know we can do it using C# but I was wondering if we can do it using VBscripting only? I am trying using "Winsock ActiveX" but was wondering if there is something else available too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Raw Sockets. I am not sure if you can use this API with VBS but you can for sure with VB. I hope this helps you. Would be nice if you shared your experience.

Greetings